# How to pass an array of string in a url

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

Hello i have an url in my jsp and i want to pass an array of string in this url to recover in my ActionForm

Comment: So, do you have Java array or JavaScript array?

Comment: i have a seven checkbox and when i click in my url i want to pass what box is checked

Comment: serialization Or json encode !

Comment: would you have a simple example

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_5-1_-_Combination_of_JSON_primitives,_JSON_object_and_JS   am not a java guy . but am using json encode in php . but this example is for java. If these are tough for you concatinate those array parameters and make it a string and pass. :)

Comment: Just remember that URLs have a limit, so I hope you are not trying to carry to much data in the query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'standard' html way of passing arrays of data: `http://mywebsite/mypage?myarray=value1&myarray=value2&myarray=value3`.  Then you can fetch all values of parameter `myarray` from request object (if framework doesn't provide more elegant ways of handling arrays).

But seeing your comment, I would recommend to leave JavaScript and just declare a form for it.
If you need a link (not button), you can always submit form from it. Something like `<a href="javascript:$('#myForm').submit();">...</a>`

Answer (score 4):

If you are dealing with something simple like a list of numeric ids, i would just run through the check boxes, create a comma separated list, and assign it to a query string parameter.  On the other side i would split the string. 
If the values are more complex you have to consider escape characters.  Also if you are dealing with a long list, the url is not the best way to pass this data.

Answer (score 0):

Try Json encode

http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Check this