# Best way to pass String array values through URL

Tags: javascript, checkboxlist, arrays

I need to pass a string array content through URL. The String array can contain 100 - 10000 values. I got the similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959609/how-to-pass-an-array-of-string-in-a-url) but problem in my case it contains large amount of data.

Using `comma (,)` is the best way to pass the values or is there any other way to solve this problem.

I am using this in `javascript function` where `String array` contains all the selected `checkbox list` values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doResend(){
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('selectedId');
var vals = "";
for (var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
  if (checkboxes[i].checked){
    vals += ","+checkboxes[i].value;
  }
}
if (vals){
vals = vals.substring(1);
window.open('resendSelectedSMS.do?smsId='+vals,"mywindow","status=1, height=335, width=400',resizable=0");
}else{
alert("Select atleast one id");
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why not store in session, and pass them.
using sessionStorage

Comment: If I were you, I'd pass that as POST, instead of GET. POST can contain much more data than a GET can. Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554896/window-open-post) will help.

Comment: Agree that post can send and fetch much more data , also it works in the background , no need to visualize your data , because sometimes you need to pass private ones.

Comment: @RichardA i will try this one this should solve the problem..

Comment: @Rohit Also look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951768/window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method).

Comment: @RichardA link gonna make my work easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Best method is using get - post :

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

something that looks like that :

```
/test/demo_form.asp?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

Comment: You'd be better off [NOT getting your information from W3S](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Comment: `/test/demo_form.asp?name1=value1&name2=value2` this is not good way as i already told it can contains thousands of values.